# Invalid argument error dusring setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

The setTimeout function throws Invalid argument error.
Can someone tell me what conversion I have to do for Settimeout to work? Thanks

```
var sessionTimeOutValue = '<%= Session.Timeout %>';
            var delay = sessionTimeOutValue * 6000; //convert to milliseconds
            setTimeout(Logout(), delay);
```

Comment: Try it like this `setTimeout(Logout, delay);` If it still does not work, what value do you get in `sessionTimeOutValue`?

Comment: You really should post the generated HTML ... as it is, we can't tell what value `sessionTimeOutValue` is.  If it is a "bad" value, then `delay` can end up equal to `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess Logout is a function which you have defined somewhere, so doing this will work

```
setTimeout(Logout, delay);
```

else

```
setTimeout(function(){Logout();},delay)
```